# Integrate Newrelic with Nativescript (ios only)

Tags: angular, nativescript, newrelic

I'm trying to Integrate NewRelic to my Nativescript(6.5) app (with Angular),
The Android part was pretty easy and I'm stuck on the ios part,
Part of the tutorial ( The pod part I did ):
Create a bridging header:

> 4. In your [app_name]-Bridging-Header.h , add the New Relic header: import "NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h"
> 5. In your AppDelegate.swift file add this call as the first line of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

The agent must be on the first line of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and ran on the main thread to ensure proper instrumentation. Starting the call later, on a background thread, or asynchronously can cause unexpected or unstable behavior.

NewRelic.start(withApplicationToken:"XXXX-NRMA")

Automatically upload your dSYM In XCode, select your project in the navigator, then click on the application target. Select Build Phases, then add a New Run Script Build Phase
In the script text area (beneath the Shell line) enter this script:

```
SCRIPT=/usr/bin/find "${SRCROOT}" -name newrelic_postbuild.sh | head -n 1
/bin/sh "${SCRIPT}" "XXXX-NRMA"
```

I'm not using xcode for develop this app,
So I'm not understanding where I need to put the [app_name]-Bridging-Header.h part
nor the Automatically upload your dSYM

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting it to work in ios requires some work.  I actually had contact with new relic and after a few days or weeks they found a solution.  This is the email we received from our contact.  Hope this helps.

•   First of all, I followed the instructions within this GitHub repo: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed.

•   Initialize the plugin…
git clone https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed nativescript-newrelicagent

cd nativescript-newrelicagent/src

npm run postclone

Answers to some of the prompts:

prompt: What will be the name of your plugin? Use lowercase characters and dashes only. Example: yourplugin / google-maps / bluetooth:  newrelicagent

prompt: Do you want to include a "TypeScript NativeScript" application linked with your plugin to make development easier (y/n)?:  (y) y

prompt: Do you want to include an "Angular NativeScript" application linked with your plugin to make development easier (y/n)?:  (n) y

npm run demo.ios

Add/configure the New Relic iOS Mobile Agent…

cd nativescript-newrelicagent/src/platforms/ios

Edit build.xcconfig file and set the contents to:

OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "CoreTelephony" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -l "c++" -l "z"

Download the latest iOS Agent from: https://download.newrelic.com/ios_agent/

Unzip the contents

Copy NewRelicAgent.framerwork to the nativescript-newrelicagent/src/platforms/io folder

Within NewRelicAgent.framework (open folder, or show package contents), do the following:

Using Xcode, create a Info.plist and set contents to:
[New Relic Plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aKeJ.png)

Create a Modules folder, and within that folder:

Create a file called module.modulemap and set its contents to:

framework module NewRelicAgent {
umbrella header "NewRelic.h"
export *
module * { export * }
link "c++"
link "z"
link framework "CoreTelephony"
link framework "SystemConfiguration"
}

Generate typings for iOS:

cd nativescript-recreate-newrelicagent/demo-angular

TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/typings" tns build ios

Create a folder called typings in nativescript-newrelicagent/src/platforms/ios

Copy file objc!NewRelicAgent.d.ts
from: nativescript-recreate-newrelicagent/demo-angular/typings
to: nativescript-newrelicagent/src/platforms/ios/typings

The plugin is now able to be added to an application by the following tns command:

tns add plugin

The New Relic’s mobile application tokens needs to the added to the application's launch event by adding NR app's token to the "NewRelicAgent.startWithApplicationToken" method as follows:[Bootstrap Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfWn6.png)

Comment: Basically you created a new plugin?
Will try it - thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you've created a successful working plugin, mind putting it on github? :)